# get straight line rotation angle in Google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-slides

Trying to get rotation angle of straight line with `getRotation()` method but it always returning **0.0**

Tried this method:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/line#getrotation

Getting output:
on line move from top or bottom always getting rotation 0.0.

```
function lineRotation() {
  var selection = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSelection();
  if(selection.getPageElementRange() !== null){

   var pageElements = selection.getPageElementRange().getPageElements()

   // Iterate each page elements
   pageElements.forEach(function(item, index) {
    if(pageElements[index].getPageElementType() == 'LINE'){
    
      var rotation = pageElements[index].asLine().getRotation();
  
 }else{
   SlidesApp.getUi().alert('Please select line.');
 }
});

  }else{
   SlidesApp.getUi().alert('Please select elements.');
  }
 }
```

Desired output required: Line rotation in angle either it moved from top or bottom.

**Update**:
Future scope - I want to get rotation and set rotation of line. If Line inclination < 45° ==> rotate horizontally or Line inclination > 45° ==> rotate vertically. https://prnt.sc/uervkw (line screenshot)

Comment: Screenshot of line?

Comment: @TheMaster I want to get rotation and set rotation of line. If Line inclination < 45° ==> rotate horizontally or Line inclination > 45° ==> rotate vertically. https://prnt.sc/uervkw (line screenshot)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Rotation != angle of the line:

Check [Line rotation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/slides/moving-elements#line_rotation):

> Like other page elements, **a line's rotation isn't the vertical angle of the line, but the rotation of its bounding box. When you create a line with specified start and end points, its rotation is always 0°**.

If you want to get the actual rotation of a line, based on its start and end points, you have to get the position of these points.

You can get these positions via [getStart()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/line#getstart) and [getEnd()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/line#getend). Both these two methods return a [Point](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/point), whose coordinates can be accessed via [getX()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/point#getX()) and [getY()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/point#gety).

Based on these coordinates, you can calculate the angle between the line and the axis you desire using some basic trigonometry.

Comment: `@lamblichus`  Thank for help. Yes it worked for me.

Comment: `@lamblichus `   I am looking for line same length after rotation posted a new question can you please recommend your suggestions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63878606/not-getting-same-line-length-after-rotation-google-apps-script-slide