# Line length changes after applying rotation transform

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

Line length, not the same when the rotation updated on a line. Suppose, when line inserted at greater than 45° angle and perform a rotation on the same the length of the line comes up different after rotation it should be the same as the inserted line length. Screenshot attached below.

```
function lineRotation() {

var selection = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSelection();
if(selection.getPageElementRange() !== null){

var pageElements = selection.getPageElementRange().getPageElements()


if(pageElements[0].getPageElementType() == 'LINE'){
  //Getting Line left position and width
  var left = pageElements[0].asLine().getLeft(),
      width = pageElements[0].asLine().getWidth(), 
      height = pageElements[0].asLine().getHeight(),
      top = pageElements[0].asLine().getTop()

  let sx1 = pageElements[0].asLine().getStart().getX();
  let sy1 = pageElements[0].asLine().getStart().getY();
  let ex1 = pageElements[0].asLine().getEnd().getX();
  let ey1 = pageElements[0].asLine().getEnd().getY();
  
  let dy = ey1 - sy1;
  let dx = ex1 - sx1;
  let theta = Math.atan2(dy,dx);
  theta *= 180/Math.PI;
  
   let dist = formatNum(Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)); //formatNum used to format result negative to positive 
  
   //Updating Line  
   if(theta > 45){ //if angle greater than 45 then it will rotate vertically else horizontally
     pageElements[0].asLine().setLineCategory(SlidesApp.LineCategory.STRAIGHT).setEnd(left, dist);
 
   }else{
    pageElements[0].asLine().setLineCategory(SlidesApp.LineCategory.STRAIGHT)
               .setEnd(left+dist, pageElements[0].asLine().getTop());
  
   }
  
 }else{
  SlidesApp.getUi().alert('Please select line.');
 }

 }else{
   SlidesApp.getUi().alert('Please select elements.');
 }
}
```

[image]

**Future Scope**: I want the same line length after rotation too.

**Output required:** when the line gets rotated its length should be the same in both cases horizontally or vertically.

[image]

Comment: What is `formatNum()`? And I cannot understand about what you want to do at the if statement of `if(theta > 45){}`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Tanaike       comments updated for if statement and formatNum function.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. I could understand about `formatNum`. But unfortunately, I cannot still understand about `if angle greater than 45 then it will rotate vertically else horizontally`. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike       Please check the updated gif example for  rotate vertically and horizontally. https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPZHx.gif

Comment: Could you please provide more information on how you want to move the lines? I'm afraid it's still not clarified by the gif example you shared. I guess you want to make the line vertical if the angle is higher than 45, and horizontal if that's not the case? Is the code you shared supposed to accomplish this? Also, the width and height correspond to the bounding box, not to the line itself, maybe this is causing a misunderstanding?

Comment: @lamblichus    Yes, everything is fine with above code only the issue is line length will change after update.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your additional information, I proposed the modification points as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Answer (score 2):

#### Modification points:

- At first, the origin of coordinates of Slide is the upper left corner.
- `left` and `top` of `setEnd(left, top)` are the coordinate of the slide as follows.

  - > `left`: The horizontal position of the end point of the line, measured in points from the upper left corner of the page.
  - > `top`: The vertical position of the end point of the line, measured in points from the upper left corner of the page.
- In your script, `left, dist` of `setEnd(left, dist)` are `var left = pageElements[0].asLine().getLeft()` and `let dist = formatNum(Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy))`, respectively. `left` is the coordinate. But `dist` is the length which is not the coordinate. In this case, it is required to add the coordinate as the offset. I think that this is the reason of your issue.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
if(theta > 45){ //if angle greater than 45 then it will rotate vertically else horizontally
  pageElements[0].asLine().setLineCategory(SlidesApp.LineCategory.STRAIGHT).setEnd(left, dist);

}else{
 pageElements[0].asLine().setLineCategory(SlidesApp.LineCategory.STRAIGHT)
            .setEnd(left+dist, pageElements[0].asLine().getTop());

}
```

To:

```
if(theta > 45){
  pageElements[0].asLine().setLineCategory(SlidesApp.LineCategory.STRAIGHT).setEnd(left, dist + sy1);
}else{
  pageElements[0].asLine().setLineCategory(SlidesApp.LineCategory.STRAIGHT).setEnd(sx1, sy1 - dist);
}
```

- In this case, it supposes that `dist` is always positive value from `formatNum used to format result negative to positive` in your script.

Result:

When above modification is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

[image]

#### Note:

- In this answer, it supposes that a line is created like your GIF animation.

#### References:

- [setEnd(left, top)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/line?hl=nb#setEnd(Number,Number))